# Does the aria-labelledby attribute require a label tag?

Tags: html, wai-aria

on an form, can the *aria-labelledby* attribute work on its own or does it require a *label* tag?

EXAMPLE:
Does it work like this

```
aria-labelledby="Name"
```

Read by the browser as "Name"?

Comment: The behavior you're looking for exists, but not in this way. Instead use `aria-label='Name'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The aria-labelledby attribute is used to indicate the IDs of the elements that are the labels for the object." ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute)).

It does not contain a text label.

So no, it doesn't work on its own.

It doesn't require a `<label>` element, but if a `<label>` is the correct HTML element for the context then you should use one. (Start with correct, semantic HTML, then build ARIA on top of it).

Comment: You can (validly) use `label` element only for HTML control elements like `input`, and for them, the `label` markup is usually sufficient. The `labelledby` attribute is useful mostly when user input is read in a different way (typically, JavaScript-driven editable `span`), so that `label' *cannot* be used.

Answer (score -2):

It requires a Label tag and is meant to work in conjunction with an associated input tag. Check out this link for more information: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-aria-in-html-20130214/#aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby

Hope this helps!

Comment: The cited document does not say that it requires “a Label tag”.